# Analytic paths through converging sequences in the complex space.

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Assume we have a Cauchy sequence $\{\vec{a_i}:i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ converging to $\vec{0}$ in $\mathbb{C}^n$ such that $|\vec{a_i}|<|\vec{a_j}|$ whenever $i>j$.
Can we find an analytic path $\phi:[0,1]\to\mathbb{C}^n$ such that
$\phi(0)=\vec{0}$ and
which passes through all points $\vec{a_n}$?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "analytic on $[0,1]$"? I assume you mean real-analytic, but since $[0,1]$ is closed, do you mean real-analytic on an open neighbourhood of $[0,1]$, or do you mean something else?

Comment: yes real analytic on an open neighborhood including $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we can't expect to do that. Let $a_n = (1/n,0)$ for $n$ odd, $a_n = (0,1/n)$ for $n$ even. The $a_n$'s are points in $\mathbb {C} = \mathbb {R}^2.$ Suppose, to reach a contradiction, that $\phi (t) = (x(t),y(t)),$ $\phi$ is real analytic on $[0,1],$ and there exist $t_n \in (0,1]$ such that $\phi (t_n) = a_n$ for all $n.$ Then $x(t_n)=0$ for $n$ even, and $y(t_n)=0$ for $n$ odd. Since the $t_n$'s are all distinct, analyticity shows $x\equiv 0, y \equiv 0,$ contradiction.

Comment: Thanks! nice counterexample. My next question would be what about asking just that $\phi$ passes just through infinitely many of the $\vec{a}_n$? Would now this weaker condition be satisfiable?